# MySQL: Link multiple records from table B, onto single record of table A in one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm designing a ticket system in PHP/MySQL.
Each ticket represents one row in the 'tickets' table.
Users can add multiple 'comments' to each ticket.

When viewing a ticket I just do an SQL query on the 'comments' table to select all comments linked to the corresponsing ticketid

However, now I have to design a search page, which returns any matching tickets and immediately show (part of, e.g. last 5) their linked comments.

I have this working by performing the same SQL query I use in the single ticket view page, but repeating this for every matching row in the search query. So if you have 1500 matching rows, that means 1500 SQL queries on the 'comments' table, yes, not very efficient...

Now I was wondering: Is there a way to join the comments table to the tickets table, but have multiple rows from the comments table 'squeezed' into one column?

I was thinking about doing a CONCAT() on the comments rows, returning them as comma-seperated values, which I could then explode() again in php to get an array containing all my comments for each ticket. But is this the most effective way or is there something better?

**EDIT:** Keep in mind that tickets which don't have any comments yet should also we returned by the query

Comment: Could you post the structure of your two tables and what fields in the `comments` table you would like to retrieve for each ticket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zane Bien answered the `CONCAT` question, I won't comment it because there is not much to add, but you also asked if it is the most effective way so I'll go for this one.

I really don't like the `CONCAT` solution. It's not the philosophy of SQL and you never know what users will write in the comment area.

As far as SQL is concerned, the right way of doing it is:

```
SELECT
    tickets.*,
    comments.*
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.ticket_id = tickets.id
WHERE tickets.title LIKE '%whatever%';
```

Then in PHP you simply iterate over the resultset and build the output. Note that the LEFT JOIN will rightfully return tickets without comments.

If you feel a bit uneasy - **but should not !** - having the ticket information on each line you can split the query in 2:

```
SELECT
    tickets.*
FROM tickets
WHERE tickets.title LIKE '%whatever%';
```

And

```
SELECT
    comments.*
FROM comments
INNER JOIN tickets ON comments.ticket_id = tickets.id
WHERE tickets.title LIKE '%whatever%';
```

That implies some more work on the application side as you'll have to link back the comments to the ticket.

My advice: go for the all-in-one query.

Comment: Wow, this was what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch! I will indeed go for the all-in-one query and sort the multiple ticket rows out in PHP.

Comment: This is the alternative solution I was about to suggest as well. It involves even more application logic in detecting changes in the `ticket_id` as you iterate through the result-set. The benefit is that you don't have to worry about delimiter risks. The drawback is that even though you only want the 5 most recent comments, you're going to have to iterate through **all** comments of each ticket in your application code. You can order the comments by date of course, but after you get the first five, you'll have to `continue;` until the `ticket_id` value changes.

Comment: Perhaps some tickets contain 800+ comments? That could slow you down slightly. I answered the question accurately as per the title ("multiple records into a single row"), but I would argue that this solution is better and would be the way to go. The benefit in completely eliminating the risk of your application breaking on certain input outweighs the drawback in *potentially* a little more render time.

Comment: If both `comments` and `tickets` have their own `id` column, your all-in-one query will return two `id` columns.

Comment: I could put a WHERE statement in this query which could filter out the  comments based on entry date, last x, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Ah yes, the typical problem of "set-grouping" that many people tend to encounter...

When we talk about *joining* multiple records (comments) onto one row (event), the only way to reliably(as in accounting for variable amounts of rows) do this using MySQL is to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` which will group information across one or more rows into a single delimited string.

You can also group information into a variable amount of actual *columns* using a feature called `PIVOT`, but unfortunately, `PIVOT` is not available in MySQL.

Either way, you will need some application logic (exploding, etc.) to format and display the subset of comments for each ticket.

As for the SQL, you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT
    a.ticket_id,
    a.ticket_title,
    a.date_created,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(LEFT(b.comment_txt, 150), '...', ':::', b.date_posted) ORDER BY b.date_posted DESC SEPARATOR '|||'), '|||', 5) AS comment_list
FROM
    tickets a
LEFT JOIN
    comments b ON a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id
WHERE
    a.ticket_title LIKE '%search_term%'
GROUP BY
    a.ticket_id
```

Everything here is fairly straightforward except for the 4th column in the `SELECT`... so let's break it down:

At the inner-most part, we have `CONCAT()`. What this does is it concatenates the fields of each comment together, so that you are able to get multiple attributes of each comment (such as the date, the actual text, and perhaps the ID, etc...).

After the `CONCAT()` alone, a single comment might look something like:

```
Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur...:::2012-06-21 00:00:00
```

The `:::` is one of the delimiters that you would `explode()` on to separate out each attribute.

Moving outwards, the `GROUP_CONCAT()` then concatenates each ***row*** together. At this point, we are basically concatenating concatenations. In addition, the most recent comments appear at the beginning of the string due to `ORDER BY b.date_posted` within the function.

The comment list might look like:

```
Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur...:::2012-06-21 00:00:00|||Cras aliquam neque quam, eget facilisis nulla...:::2012-06-18 00:00:00
```

The `|||` is the delimiter you would use to separate out each comment.

Moving out further, the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` only selects the first five comments. Since we ordered the comments by most recent first, it's essentially only selecting the five most recent comments in each ticket.

Then in your PHP code, you could do roughly:

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    {
        // First check if the ticket has comments. Value will be NULL if not.
        if(!empty($ticket['comment_list']))
        {
            foreach(explode('|||', $ticket['comment_list']) as $comment)
            {
                $attributes = explode(':::', $comment);

                $comment_preview = $attributes[0]; // Get first attribute
                $date_posted = $attributes[1]; // Get second attribute
            }
        }
    }
```

I use those particular delimiters because commas can be present in fields like the title, etc. and you would not want your script to separate the string in the wrong places. This possibility of erroneous separation is one of the major downsides to using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so you must decide which delimiters would be best to use based on the unlikelihood that they would be present within the field values.

Comment: Thanks for you suggest Zane, this is what I was referring to in my question, but thanks for writing it out more clean.
Thing is, this ticket system is to be used for interaction between developer and high-level support desks, so the comments are bound to contain pieces of code here and there. I think it's only a matter of time until someone put my delimiter string into a comment.



I'm going to wait if someone can come up with a nicer solution, if not I'll accept this answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You could store your comment text values as Base64, which means there will never be a clash with the delimiters if you use . which is not a valid Base64 character. You could also roll your own encoding which filters out whichever delimiter you are looking at using.

Answer (score 1):

The comments must have a record of the ticket ID for them to to be related so you should be able to grab the ID from the ticket and use a JOIN to grab the comments.

I am doing something very similar with a Wordpress DB so I can only go by that layout. In wordpress the post has an ID which relates to the comment.

So you should be able to do it with one query I think. That is if the design of the tables allows for this type of association – which it should.

```
SELECT tickets.ID, tickets.title, tickets.content, comments.content 
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ticket_id = tickets.ID
WHERE tickets.content LIKE '%the search term%'
ORDER BY comments.comment_date
```

I only have a functional grasp of SQL so other guys on here may correct me in the right way to do this but I think it should work. The actual search element of this query is just for the example I don't know what it is you are actually searching.

Revised:

```
$query = "SELECT tickets.ID ticket_id, tickets.title title, tickets.content content
          FROM tickets
          WHERE tickets.content LIKE '%the search term%'
          AND tickets.title LIKE '%the search term%'";

$tickets = $db->fetch_array($query);


foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    echo "<h1>$ticket['title']</h1>";
    echo "<h1>$ticket['content']</h1>";

    $query = "SELECT comments.title title, comments.content content
              FROM comments
              WHERE comments.ID = {$ticket['ticket_id']}
              ORDER BY comments.date DESC
              LIMIT 5";

    $comments = $db->fetch_array($query); 

    if ($comments) {

       echo "<div class="comments">";

       foreach($comments as $comment) {
          echo "<div class="comment">";
          echo "<h1>$comment['title']</h1>";
          echo "<h1>$comment['content']</h1>";
          echo "</div>";
       }

       echo "</div>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Just realised I am pulling the ticket multiple times for no reason...

Oliver has the right idea, break the query up by getting the ticket first and then grab the comments using the tickets ID. Unless you need to search the content of the comments too!

Comment: If you do that it will only show 1 comments.content field, containing just one comment

Comment: The first query is wrong really I have just left it in to show the workings out and my misguided logic.

Comment: You could take the group by out of the first query to get all comments and order by date and date but doing it all in one go removes flexibility

Comment: That last edit you made is actually what I have now, query the comments every time for each ticket you're looping through, but this results in 1 SQL query for each ticket. If your search query has a 1500 row result set, you will end up doing 1500 other SQL queries to show all the comments, this does work but is not very clean or efficient.

Comment: The more I think about it the latter is the clearer and most readable way to do it and it only actually does one extra query per ticket. So on 30 results you have 31 queries. You shouldn't really be pulling a 1500 row result set, you should use a LIMIT and page your results LIMIT 0, 30, LIMIT 31, 61 etc etc.